# Accurate device orientation from Epson Moverio BT-200 in Unity 3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, sensor-fusion, epson-moverio

I'm currently facing quite a challenging problem when trying to get a continuous, accurate orientation of the Epson Moverio BT-200 in Unity. I'm able to get quite good results for the user when he is looking up/down (already when I'm only using the accelerometer), but not for left/right movements. The left/right movements work somehow ok when relying only on the device's gyroscope with the following code part, but there is still a drift after some time which i need to remove.

```
Quaternion newAttitude = new Quaternion (gyro.attitude.x, gyro.attitude.y,    gyro.attitude.z, gyro.attitude.w);
transform.rotation = newAttitude;
Vector3 ea = newAttitude.eulerAngles;
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-ea[0], -ea[1], ea[2]);
```

I already tried using the Android internal `getOrientation` method and various other sensor fusion tutorials and implementations (e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729759/Android-Sensor-Fusion-Tutorial). ANY small hint is absolutely appreciated. :) Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that "left/right rotation" is a rotation around an axis following gravity direction.

In that case, it is not possible to remove drift using only gyroscope and accelerometer. You need to integrate a third sensor that provides a constant reference of a direction not parallel to gravity. 
The magnetometer is commonly used for this purpose, since it provides a fixed reference of magnetic field direction that can be used to mitigate drift.

This sensor is actually used in the tutorial you have referenced. Apart from the complementary sensor, you can use more powerful alternatives as Extended or Unscented Kalman filters, Mahony's DCM filter, etc.

Comment: yeah, i know, i already tried that - but with no success.... And i decided to go with a Complementary Filter for the beginning because it is much easier to implement than a Kalman filter. I have the feeling that it has something to do with the combination of the device and unity...

Comment: Check thoroughly the conventions for each reference system! It is a pretty common mistake mixing left- and right-handed systems or NED with ENU. You should be using a consistent convention through the whole algorithm.

Comment: that should work fine (as i said using only the gyroscope or the sensor fusion for looking up/down works). It's a matter of some sort of jittering left/right and not providing values you can use as a basis and work with

Comment: What do you mean with "and not providing values you can use as a basis and work with"? Anyway, please double check coordinate system conventions in Unity/Android/sensors, and also in the complementay filter... I learnt the hard way that those mistakes can be difficult to spot because apparently work fine in some situations.

Comment: There is no smooth movement for looking left right, the values change from one reading to the other up to 25°. As I said the coordinate system is adapted, that works fine. I also tried the native Android Sourcecode by copying it, and even that does not work the way it should